# Is there any way to pass unnamed parameter to stored procedure through SqlCommand (ADO.NET)?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I write a simple wrapper for sp calls using SqlCommand Type==StoredProcedure. I just want to pass parameter there without specifying its name. How can i do it? cmd.Parameters.Add(param) doesn't work, it gets only SqlParameter instance.
Thank you for replies,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying to use [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) to populate the parameters collection?

Usage :

```
// Create Command
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

// Open Connection
connection.Open();

// Discover Parameters for Stored Procedure and populate command.Parameters Collection.
// Causes Rountrip to Database.
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
```

You would obviously need to then populate the values for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't pass a Parameter without ParameterName. However, if you use Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block, you can do something like this:

```
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DatabaseName");
        DbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP Name Here");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        db.DiscoverParameters(cmd);
```

Now your Command object will contain all the parameter information.